# FittedBox that may expand in Width and allow Row to SpaceBetween inside it

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a ListView of Containers. Inside those containers I want this to happen:

**On Large (width) screens (expand text as if with spacedBetween):**
[image]

**On Small (width) screens (shrink all text and fontsize as a box, keeping them equally sized):**

[image]

**"Short Explanation"**
How can I achieve this with this code? Is it even possible? If not, why?

```
Container(
    color: Colors.white,
    child: Row(
      children: [
        ItemIcon(),
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            padding: myPaddingHere,
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                ItemDataTitle(titleData),
                SizedBox(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  child: FittedBox(
                    fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: IntrinsicWidth(
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          ItemDataText(type1, data1),
                          ItemDataText(type2, data2),
                          ItemDataText(type3, data3),
                          ItemDataText(type4, data4),
                          ItemDataText(type5, data5),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        ItemEndIcon(endData),
      ],
    ),
  )
```

ItemDataText code:

```
Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: myPaddingTop),
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children: [
      Text(_text),
      Text(_value ?? '--'),
    ],
  ),
)
```

**"Long Explanation"**

The left image is a Container, with defined Height limiting an Image widget. The right image is a Container with an IconButton with defined Width. Both may be seen as ItemIcon and ItemEndIcon respectively.

In the middle I've got and Expanded widget (with some padding) and a Column with a Title (ItemDataTitle) and a Body. This body(called data) is a Column of widgets called ItemDataText, which are simply a Row of 2 Texts.

How can I make an widget that let me Expanded the width of the ItemDataText content, when I have space for it (for example with spaceBetween) and at the same time, have a box around all those texts allowing me to shrink them (fonts) when the screen is too small?

It seems to me that FittedBox also constrains it's children in some way or (if I don't use IntrinsicWidth) stops spacedBetween from working properly, bringing together those 2 texts inside my ItemDataText widget.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

We can think this item as

```
Row < start, middle, end >    
where middle = Column[name, spacer, value]
```

- To fix text overflow, you can use `overflow` property to fixed line, or wrap `Text` with `Flexible` widget.

You can include your decoration in it.

```dart
Row(
  children: [
    Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Icon(
        Icons.ac_unit,
        size: 45,
      ),
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          ...List.generate(
              4,
              (index) => Row(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        "name $index",
                        overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
                        maxLines: 1,
                      ),
                      Spacer(),
                      Flexible(
                          child: Text(
                              "Description ssssssssssssss$index")),
                    ],
                  )).toList(),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Icon(
        Icons.delete,
        size: 45,
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

[image]

Comment: The major problem is that this does not take in account the requisit of everything inside the middle to be squished/scaled down if it doesn't have enough space. Your solution is actually my code (provided) without the Fittedbox which does seems necessary to fill the missing requisit, but it breaks the Spacer and Flexible of the middle part. Any other suggestions?

Comment: After testing my approach, can you share what exactly went wrong?

Comment: Sure! As I mentioned, `child: FittedBox(fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,alignment: Alignment.center)` is almost a requirement in this case. The text inside the `middle` part needs to scale down when there is not enough space for it. But it also need to "expand" in width when the screen allows it. Your way of thinking is already being used and I have a similar setup with `Row(children: [ItemIcon(),Expanded(...),ItemEndIcon(endData)])`. Those screenshots are from a real Flutter application with the code I provided. The main issue is related to the FittedBox and how can it Expand in width when possible.

Comment: When the screen is small, I need the whole `middle` part to be scaled down, when it can't fit on screen. It expands horizontally when it can, allowing my text and a `Spacer` to work, but it is also inside a `FittedBox` so that it is scaled down when there's no space on screen (maybe a flexible with scaledown?). Your solution does work to take all space with the `Expanded` and `Spacer`, but if I were to put it inside a smaller screen (even smalled than the content of the middle part), you'll get an horizonta overflow on the row inside the middle part (on each line or in some of them).

Comment: If I ever face this issue, I will use layout builder for getting screen size and fitting the widget or making it scrollable. Using `FittedBox`  may be an option, but there are others way to look around and solve a single problem in many ways.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up making an workaround and setting a fixed size based on the screen size. This is really terrible in Flutter. For something that takes so much in account layout, its literally impossible to do something in the layout that I do in one or two css properties.

Comment: I would say `my knowledge is terrible in Flutter` you can dig dive into https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout